# Graphics card incompatibility nVidia GeForce8300 GS Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: graphics, 13.04, visual-artifacts

I installed Ubuntu 13.04. I first tried installing via CD but the install would freeze on the second step every time. I made a USB and the install ran perfectly. I restarted the machine and everything loaded fine. I get to the login screen and login to my account. This appears to be functioning normally as well. However, as soon as I click on something, the screen goes wild with thousands of colored boxes that change and move with mouse movement and clicks.

As this now appears to be an incompatibility with my graphics card, here is more information on that. I have a Dell Inspiron 530 and a look up of that gives the graphics card as being an nVidia GeForce8300 GS according to [Dell Product Support Page](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/04/Servicetag/1HQW8F1?s=DHS).

I am unable to access any sort of settings pages on the computer itself as the display problems make it entirely impossible. Would it be possible to remotely log into the computer and change preferences somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Dell Inspiron 530 as well and was having the same problem. After a fresh install from a USB thumb drive I was able to do the following:
1. Boot the system and get a terminal that was visually displaying correctly via Ctrl+Alt+T.
2. From the command prompt: sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
3. After the install rebooted the system and it was good.

Answer (score 2):

I switched to Ubuntu 13.04 a few weeks ago and was having the same problem. It was a problem with my graphics card driver working with Ubuntu.

It's kinda hard with all the glitches going on but if you can manage to run the updates the Software Updater provides then go to **System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers** and switch from the X.org ones to the **fglrx update** drivers. Hit apply and let it finish loading,then reboot your computer.

Comment: I am completely unable to access the settings panel to make any changes as after the first click I make the entire screen goes crazy.

Comment: You can try booting in failsafe mode and reinstalling drivers that way.Run sudo apt-get install nvidia-current followed by sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates